# How to Access folder in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, decompiling, inria-spoon

[directory structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpnY6.png)

i want to access CFRDecompiler folder under decompiled folder from a java main function, how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

can try this code
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:decompiled/CFRDecompiler/")

Comment: this didn't work Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [decompiled/CFRDecompiler/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not exist

Comment: Hi, this is the right way to access  local file code try again this "classpath:decompiled/CFRDecompiler/samplefile.json"